# Optional Chaining Error Not Not About ES2020

Tags: typescript

I am having an issue with using optional chaining in my project. When I use something like:

```
this.props.someString?.toUpperCase()
```

It does not cause any syntax errors in VS Code but causes a runtime error

`Module parse failed: Unexpected token (33:38) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

Both previous posts about this issue on StackOverflow only state to change the target in the tsconfig to es2020 or es2018. I have tried this and it does not work. I'm not sure what other context about my environment to post. I am not using Babel and my TS version is 3.9.9^.

Edit: tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Change the target to `es2019` or `es2018` should fix the issue. Can we see the content of `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @Paleo That's why I made this post - because changing the target to es2020,es2019, es2018 all don't work and that seems to be the solution on both StackOverflow and the internet. Updated post with tsconfig.

Comment: With `es2020` the optional chaining syntax is kept and it is normal that at runtime the execution fails. Are you sure that with `es2019` or `es2018` you have the same error message?

Comment: Yes, I've tested it with both as the target and recompile each time. They both fail at runtime.

Comment: I don't understand why. But I suggest to find the compiled code, then to look at the character line 33, column 38 ( _"Unexpected token (33:38)"_).

Comment: Any idea how I can view the compiled code? Using outDir and rootDir don't really do anything...